# Permabots keyboard template with jinja2

Tags: python, django, jinja2, telegram

I'm going crazy. This is just boring. No docs. Nothing.

Also I'm not good neither in python or jinja2.

I know this is the real problem but for now, I need your help.

Permabots is a app built in django for managing telegram bots, I'm a fan of python so I want to learn this app bot in a very basic stage, I cannot write keyboard response in jinja2 as the app wants.

Just show me how to do it.

Tnks.

http://www.permabots.com/docs/getting-started
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup

Comment: You need to ask a *specific* question. What, exactly, are you trying to do and what is your exact problem?

Comment: i want to create a costume keyboard in response a command in telegram bots. now, the keyboard code must be written in jinja2 .

Comment: http://www.permabots.com/docs/getting-started#context

Comment: just take look at this link, in the context section, you can see the bot handler code. in the bottom of that peace of code, you will see the keyboard template.

Comment: "keyboard_template": "{% if response.status == 200 %}[['Repos'],['Back']]{% endif %}"

Comment: OK, and.. what is the problem?

Comment: this is all, how i could write my own keyboard template? is there any basic rules? or anything that helps.